# Would it be too difficult to implementing SASS in the midst of project?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have built 80% of my portfolio site using just regular CSS 3 without CSS preprocessors. Will it be too complicated (late) to start transferring everything to SASS? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the SCSS syntax instead of the whitespace-sensitive SASS syntax (both are supported by every SASS processor I know about), you can gradually migrate the code to use the features of SASS. Unless you have something in your code that confuses the SCSS parser (I've never experienced this), it should be painless to migrate plain CSS to SCSS.

Ultimately, as you recognize repetition in your code, you can refactor that into SASS mixins and variables, but you can do that as it make sense.

The whitespace-sensitive (or "indented" syntax) is an older format and is now less popular than the SCSS variant. Basically, anything on the same indentation level is a child of whatever is indented "less" than that. Example:

```sass
.myclass
   :color red
   :font-size 0.2em
```

This would just be like the below SCSS:

```css
.myclass {
   color: red;
   font-size: 0.2em;
}
```

But most people use the SCSS dialect instead, these days, which looks basically like regular CSS except that it supports nested selector declarations, substitution variables, and mixins.

Comment: どうもありがとうございます ：）Good to know that migration isn't complicated. I will try it. Could you give an example of whitespace-sensitive SASS? I haven't heard of it.

Comment: @YongJunJung sure, I've added a contrasting example.